# automatically reference dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget

i am new with creation nuget packages.

I create the directories folder and copy in the lib directory all the assembly that i want to distribute with nuget.

I configured VS2012 to get package from local source.
When i add my package to a new project, i see that all my assembly are added to the references.
All works fine, but i have a problem with an external dll (log4net.dll) that i have to reference for correct working. 
I add the dependency node and i see in the download package directory the log4net.dll correctly downloaded, but the dll is not added to the references of the project.

What i have missed ?

Thanks in advance,
Giuseppe.

Comment: _"the dll is not added to the references of the project"_ - it should. How did you update your package in your project?

Comment: I use the "Manage nuget package for solution" menu e choose the local storage. Then i click install for the package i see in the list.

Comment: Can you post your .nuget file?

Comment: If you are adding the package at the solution level then you haven't added it to the project and that is why no references were created. Add the NuGet package to the project that needs it, rather than (or in addition to) the solution.

Comment: Also, if you create a .nuspec file with the same name as your .csproj file containing just the metadata (no files) then you can supply the .csproj file to nuget pack instead of the nuspec file. NuGet will then find the nuspec file and use the metadata from it, and it will infer dependencies from the project file, saving you some work. For simple packages, that's a really neat and simple way to create nuget packages. It comes undone for more complex packages though.